# npm - Fail to install. What is 'make'?

Tags: node.js, npm

When you are a newbie, you ask silly question. I've tried my best to Google and stack around before asking here. There is a similar question but no clear answer: [npm failed to install time with make not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772508/npm-failed-to-install-time-with-make-not-found-error)

I tried to 'npm install' and got an error. Something to do with 'make'. What is 'make'? What do I need to install to get 'make'. My system is nodejs SmartOS.

```
bcrypt@0.6.0 install /home/scotch/node_modules/bcrypt
node-gyp rebuild
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack at F (/opt/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:43:28)
gyp ERR! stack at E (/opt/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:46:29)
gyp ERR! stack at /opt/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:57:16
gyp ERR! stack at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
gyp ERR! System SunOS 5.11
gyp ERR! command "node" "/opt/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/scotch/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.24
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: Try to install into this way->[ppa:chris-lea/node.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager), this include `npm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is 'make'? See this: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29)

To install for SmartOS: pkgin in gmake

To continue to install bcrypt: reboot the machine.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize what I learned here: [npm failed to install time with make not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772508/npm-failed-to-install-time-with-make-not-found-error)

I had this issue installing the mqtt package

make is a build tool for commandline.

To install:

On CENTOS 7 and RHEL 7:

RUN yum install -y make gcc*

On Ubuntu (where I had my issue) this command worked:

$ sudo apt-get install build-essential

Also, I am not sure if this is necessary but I removed the failed packages before reinstalling.