# npm install mongoose causes gyp and kerberos errors (gssapi/gssapi.h file not found)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, mongoose, kerberos, node-gyp

**Ubuntu 14.04**

**nodejs** version is **v4.1.1**
installed with these commands:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

**mongodb** installed via [mongodb docs tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Next I tried installing **mongoose** by doing

```
sudo npm install mongoose
```

I received the following error:

```
> kerberos@0.0.14 install /root/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)

gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:73:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:76:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:84:16
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-57-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /root/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
gyp ERR! node -v v4.1.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
mongoose@4.1.9 node_modules/mongoose
├── async@0.9.0
├── hooks-fixed@1.1.0
├── regexp-clone@0.0.1
├── mpromise@0.5.4
├── mpath@0.1.1
├── muri@1.0.0
├── ms@0.1.0
├── sliced@0.0.5
├── kareem@1.0.1
├── bson@0.4.12
├── mquery@1.6.3 (debug@2.2.0, bluebird@2.9.26)
└── mongodb@2.0.42 (es6-promise@2.1.1, readable-stream@1.0.31, mongodb-core@1.2.10)
```

I tried installing **make** via

```
sudo apt-get install make
```

Tried installing mongoose via npm again, received following error:

```
> kerberos@0.0.14 install /root/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory `/root/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o] Error 127
make: Leaving directory `/root/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-57-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /root/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
gyp ERR! node -v v4.1.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
mongoose@4.1.9 node_modules/mongoose
├── async@0.9.0
├── hooks-fixed@1.1.0
├── regexp-clone@0.0.1
├── mpromise@0.5.4
├── mpath@0.1.1
├── muri@1.0.0
├── ms@0.1.0
├── sliced@0.0.5
├── kareem@1.0.1
├── bson@0.4.12
├── mquery@1.6.3 (debug@2.2.0, bluebird@2.9.26)
└── mongodb@2.0.42 (es6-promise@2.1.1, readable-stream@1.0.31, mongodb-core@1.2.10)
```

I tried installing **g++** via

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

tried installing mongoose again, received error:

```
> kerberos@0.0.14 install /root/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory `/root/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
In file included from ../lib/kerberos.cc:1:0:
../lib/kerberos.h:5:27: fatal error: gssapi/gssapi.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gssapi/gssapi.h>
                           ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/root/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-57-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /root/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
gyp ERR! node -v v4.1.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
mongoose@4.1.9 node_modules/mongoose
├── async@0.9.0
├── hooks-fixed@1.1.0
├── regexp-clone@0.0.1
├── mpromise@0.5.4
├── mpath@0.1.1
├── muri@1.0.0
├── ms@0.1.0
├── sliced@0.0.5
├── kareem@1.0.1
├── bson@0.4.12
├── mquery@1.6.3 (debug@2.2.0, bluebird@2.9.26)
└── mongodb@2.0.42 (es6-promise@2.1.1, readable-stream@1.0.31, mongodb-core@1.2.10)
```

Any ideas as to what my issue(s) are?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try installing the Kerberos Development Package:

```
apt-get install libkrb5-dev
```

Comment: Or for Red Hat like `yum install krb5-devel`

Comment: Worked for me on GCE. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Solution for Dockerfile don't miss apt-get update

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libkrb5-dev
```

Because you have an error.

```
E: Package 'libkrb5-dev' has no installation candidate
```