# Error when installing mongodb module using NPM

Tags: node.js, mongodb, installation, npm

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb)
I have a package.json file which has the following contents:

```
{
  "name": "NodeMongo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mongodb": "~2.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/arendu/NodeMongo.git"
  },
  "dependencies" : {
      "mongodb": "~2.0"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/arendu/NodeMongo/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/arendu/NodeMongo"
}
```

As per the tutorial I should now install the dependencies using

```
>npm install
```

I get the following error:

```
>npm install
npm WARN package.json NodeMongo@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json NodeMongo@1.0.0 No README data
|
> kerberos@0.0.15 install /Users/arenduchintala/Projects/NodeMongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/worker.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberosgss.o
make: cc: No such file or directory
make: *** [Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberosgss.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 13.4.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/arenduchintala/Projects/NodeMongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
mongodb@2.0.45 node_modules/mongodb
├── es6-promise@2.1.1
├── readable-stream@1.0.31 (isarray@0.0.1, inherits@2.0
```

How can I go about fixing this error?

Comment: you have "dependencies" listed twice. Try removing one of them.

Comment: Also, try installing xcode command line tools if you don't have it.

Comment: sorry 2 dependencies was a typo, it does not work (same error) even after removing it. I also have command line tools.

Comment: try `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm install mongoose causes gyp and kerberos errors (gssapi/gssapi.h file not found)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32919589/npm-install-mongoose-causes-gyp-and-kerberos-errors-gssapi-gssapi-h-file-not-fo)