# MongoDb driver for nodejs install error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

I'm trying to install Mongo driver for NodeJs and i get some error on the npm install. The node version I'm using is 4.2.0 and the mongo version i have in the dependencies is ~2.0 . I'm not sure if is ok, or is because i'm missing some dependecies.

The plaform where i'm trying to install it is:

Linux pcname 3.2.0-4-rt-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux

And NodeJS is compiled from source.

```
npm install mongodb
npm WARN package.json test_project@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json test_project@1.0.0 No README data
\
> kerberos@0.0.15 install /path_to_project/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)

make: se ingresa al directorio `/path_to_project/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
In file included from ../lib/kerberos.cc:1:0:
../lib/kerberos.h:5:27: fatal error: gssapi/gssapi.h: File or directory doesn't exist
 #include <gssapi/gssapi.h>
                           ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o] Error 1
make: se sale del directorio `/path_to_project/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-4-rt-amd64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /path_to_project/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm install mongoose causes gyp and kerberos errors (gssapi/gssapi.h file not found)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32919589/npm-install-mongoose-causes-gyp-and-kerberos-errors-gssapi-gssapi-h-file-not-fo)

Comment: Oh,was that, thank you. Sorry for opening a new question.

Comment: Great big blue button you should be pressing instead that basically states that other question is the same thing as yours.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

> sudo apt-get install libkrb5-dev