# Node-gyp build fails. Unable to figure out what is causing the issue

Tags: node.js, build, node-modules, node-gyp, node-addon-api

Iam trying to install the jsonski package, but Iam encountering issues with node-gyp while doing so. I am able to run the **node-gyp configure** command without issues as seen below,

```
ubuntu@Ubuntu-22:~/JSON/JSONSki$ node-gyp configure
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
gyp info using node@14.21.3 | linux | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.6 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/ubuntu/JSON/JSONSki/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/ubuntu/.cache/node-gyp/14.21.3/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/ubuntu/.cache/node-gyp/14.21.3',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/lib/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/ubuntu/.cache/node-gyp/14.21.3/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/ubuntu/JSON/JSONSki',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info ok
```

but the **node-gyp build **command fails. My binding.gyp file contains the following.

```
ubuntu@Ubuntu-22:~/JSON/JSONSki$ node-gyp build
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
gyp info using node@14.21.3 | linux | x64
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
make: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/JSON/JSONSki/build'
make: *** No rule to make target 'Release/obj.target/binding//home/ubuntu/JSON/JSONSki/src/JSONPathParser.o', needed by 'Release/obj.target/binding.node'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/JSON/JSONSki/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:203:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:285:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.19.0-35-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/bin/node-gyp" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/JSON/JSONSki
gyp ERR! node -v v14.21.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

My **binding.gyp** file is as follows.

```
{
  'targets': [
    {
      "target_name": "binding",
      "sources": [ '/home/ubuntu/JSON/JSONSki/src/JSONPathParser.cpp',
        '/home/ubuntu/JSON/JSONSki/src/JSONPathParser.h'
        '/home/ubuntu/JSON/JSONSki/src/QueryAutomaton.h'
        '/home/ubuntu/JSON/JSONSki/src/QueryProcessor.cpp'
        '/home/ubuntu/JSON/JSONSki/src/QueryProcessor.h'
        '/home/ubuntu/JSON/JSONSki/src/RecordLoader.cpp'
        '/home/ubuntu/JSON/JSONSki/src/RecordLoader.h'
        '/home/ubuntu/JSON/JSONSki/src/Records.h']
    }
  ],
  'include_dirs': ["<!(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include_dir\")"],
  'defines': [ 'NODE_ADDON_API_ENABLE_MAYBE' ],
}
```

Here is my **package.json** file content.

```
{
  "name": "ubuntu",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "cmake-js": "^7.2.1",
    "node-addon-api": "^6.0.0",
    "node-gyp": "^9.3.1",
    "nopt": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "install": "node-gyp rebuild"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "gypfile": true
}
```

I have tried all the solutions provided in the below mentioned links, but none seem to fix the issue. I have also tried using nvm to install all versions of node form 14 to 19, still no luck. I have python 3.10.6 and gcc version 11.3.2 on my system.

1. https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/809
2. [GYP ERR! build error. stack Error: 'make' failed with exit code 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316064/gyp-err-build-error-stack-error-make-failed-with-exit-code-2/55590251#55590251)
3. [npm failed to install time with make not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772508/npm-failed-to-install-time-with-make-not-found-error)
4. [npm install mongoose causes gyp and kerberos errors (gssapi/gssapi.h file not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32919589/npm-install-mongoose-causes-gyp-and-kerberos-errors-gssapi-gssapi-h-file-not-fo)

Any leads on how to get Jsonski running would be helpful.