# Unable to install dependencies on my gatsby dev blog

Tags: npm, gatsby

I'm having trouble starting my gatsby `bee-starter` dev blog. I just cloned it from my repository after installing Ubuntu 20.04LTS on my system. Usually it works by `npm start` but I don't know it does not. I also tried `npm install` but no. After I tried to install `gatsby-plugin-manifest` but again, I keep getting errors like ELIFECYCLE. I don't really understand what that means. Could someone help me out and figure out what's really going on? Thanks!

```js
localhost@localhost:~/Desktop/devBlog$ npm install

> sharp@0.21.3 install /home/hellRaiser/Desktop/devBlog/node_modules/sharp
> (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)

info sharp Using cached /home/hellRaiser/.npm/_libvips/libvips-8.7.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=12.16.2 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=linux)
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:167:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-26-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/hellRaiser/Desktop/devBlog/node_modules/sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sharp@0.21.3 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.21.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/hellRaiser/.npm/_logs/2020-05-01T13_25_04_789Z-debug.log
```

```js
localhost@localhost:~/Desktop/devBlog$ npm start

> gatsby-starter-bee@0.1.0 start /home/hellRaiser/Desktop/devBlog
> npm run develop


> gatsby-starter-bee@0.1.0 develop /home/hellRaiser/Desktop/devBlog
> gatsby develop

success open and validate gatsby-configs — 0.005 s
error UNHANDLED REJECTION


  Error: Unable to find plugin "gatsby-plugin-manifest". Perhaps you need to install its package?

  - load.js:107 resolvePlugin
    [devBlog]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/load-plugins/load.js:107:11

  - load.js:150 processPlugin
    [devBlog]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/load-plugins/load.js:150:20

  - load.js:169 
    [devBlog]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/load-plugins/load.js:169:20

  - Array.forEach

  - load.js:168 module.exports
    [devBlog]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/load-plugins/load.js:168:20

  - index.js:56 
    [devBlog]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/load-plugins/index.js:56:21

  - Generator.next

  - new Promise

  - index.js:96 
    [devBlog]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/load-plugins/index.js:96:17

  - index.js:126 
    [devBlog]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/index.js:126:36

  - Generator.next


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gatsby-starter-bee@0.1.0 develop: `gatsby develop`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-starter-bee@0.1.0 develop script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/hellRaiser/.npm/_logs/2020-05-01T13_32_13_638Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gatsby-starter-bee@0.1.0 start: `npm run develop`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-starter-bee@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/hellRaiser/.npm/_logs/2020-05-01T13_32_13_723Z-debug.log
```

```js
localhost@localhost:~/Desktop/devBlog$ npm install gatsby-plugin-manifest

> sharp@0.21.3 install /home/hellRaiser/Desktop/devBlog/node_modules/sharp
> (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)

info sharp Using cached /home/hellRaiser/.npm/_libvips/libvips-8.7.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=12.16.2 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=linux)
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:167:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-26-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/hellRaiser/Desktop/devBlog/node_modules/sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.4.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-graphql@2.1.1 requires a peer of graphql@^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN express-graphql@0.6.12 requires a peer of graphql@^0.10.0 || ^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN graphql-tools@3.1.1 requires a peer of graphql@^0.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN gatsby-plugin-manifest@2.4.1 requires a peer of gatsby@^2.4.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sharp@0.21.3 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.21.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/hellRaiser/.npm/_logs/2020-05-01T13_33_06_861Z-debug.log
```

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "gatsby-starter-bee",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Gatsby blog starter template",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "Jbee[JaeYeopHan]<ljyhanll@gmail.com>",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/JaeYeopHan/gatsby-starter-bee/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^2.2.8",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.0.34",
    "gatsby-plugin-feed": "^2.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "^2.0.17",
    "gatsby-plugin-lodash": "^3.0.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.0.24",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^2.0.25",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.0.10",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.0.11",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.0.30",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^2.0.10",
    "gatsby-plugin-typography": "^2.2.10",
    "gatsby-remark-autolink-headers": "^2.0.16",
    "gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files": "^2.0.11",
    "gatsby-remark-emoji": "0.0.2",
    "gatsby-remark-images": "^3.0.10",
    "gatsby-remark-images-medium-zoom": "^1.2.1",
    "gatsby-remark-prismjs": "^3.2.6",
    "gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe": "^2.1.1",
    "gatsby-remark-smartypants": "^2.0.9",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.0.28",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.3.8",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.1.17",
    "intersection-observer": "^0.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "prismjs": "^1.15.0",
    "react": "^16.8.1",
    "react-disqus-comments": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.1",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-switch": "^5.0.0",
    "react-typography": "^0.16.13",
    "smooth-scroll": "^16.0.0",
    "typeface-catamaran": "0.0.54",
    "typeface-merriweather": "0.0.72",
    "typeface-montserrat": "0.0.54",
    "typeface-noto-sans-kr": "0.0.63",
    "typography": "^0.16.17",
    "typography-theme-github": "^0.16.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "eslint": "^5.14.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "fs-extra": "^7.0.1",
    "gray-matter": "^4.0.2",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "lighthousebot": "git+https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/lighthousebot.git",
    "prettier": "^1.14.2",
    "recursive-readdir": "^2.2.2",
    "signale": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/JaeYeopHan/gatsby-starter-bee#readme",
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "n/a",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/JaeYeopHan/gatsby-starter-bee.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post": "node ./cli/create-new-post.js",
    "dev": "gatsby develop",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.jsx --ignore-pattern public .",
    "deploy": "gatsby build && gh-pages -d public -b master -r 'git@github.com:${50904633}/${github page name}.github.io.git'",
    "format": "prettier --trailing-comma es5 --no-semi --single-quote --write 'src/**/*.js' 'src/**/*.md'",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "lh": "lighthousebot",
    "fix-semi": "eslint --quiet --ignore-pattern node_modules --ignore-pattern public --parser babel-eslint --no-eslintrc --rule '{\"semi\": [2, \"never\"], \"no-extra-semi\": [2]}' --fix gatsby-node.js"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm start` is not universal. It depends on the scripts defined in `package.json`.

The easiest way to get starting is to install [gatsby-cli](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/quick-start/#install-the-gatsby-cli):

```
npm install -g gatsby-cli
```

Then just follow the instructions on the [starter](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/JaeYeopHan/gatsby-starter-bee/) page:

```
gatsby new gatsby-starter-bee https://github.com/JaeYeopHan/gatsby-starter-bee
```

It should download and install everything. Then just:

```
cd gatsby-starter-bee
gatsby develop
```

And you should have a working development site on localhost.

Comment: I have this site deployed on netlify and works on localhost too, but after I reinstalled my OS, I had to clone it again, so I think that's the problem. I have already many commits to this repo fo mine. It's just that I have to make it build somehow.

Comment: Ah, then you're probably missing some build tools. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/14772631/532431

Comment: Idk, it's already updated `build-essential is already the newest version (12.8ubuntu1)`

Comment: I think the problem is what I'm getting here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61556816/npm-install-failed-gatsby-dev-blog