# npm install failed gatsby dev blog

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, gatsby, node-gyp

I've been spending hours on this problem of my gatsby dev blog. I cloned it from my repository and ran `npm install`, also with sudo privilege, but it failed. Could anyone tell me what's the issue?

Here's the error that I'm getting:

```js
localhost@localhost:~/Desktop/devBlog$ sudo npm install
[sudo] password for hellRaiser: 
npm WARN tarball tarball data for typeface-montserrat@0.0.54 (sha512-Typhap0PWT299+Va0G/8ZtycHMXrH4gBWKfiW977KEBx5rXUUCa70gvqLx1fdA0WAo6bhSAQmo8uc+QFAmjPww==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for typeface-merriweather@0.0.72 (sha512-gO0+fcZ1fTyKUsYY1ltYOOTI6FmBGeEdyIfeQg9NL8aInndk0feiJJVJsKHm/DiyYrnQEezraAQhz/KQoqMGtw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.

> sharp@0.21.3 install /home/hellRaiser/Desktop/devBlog/node_modules/sharp
> (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)

ERR! sharp EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.npm'    
info sharp Attempting to build from source via node-gyp but this may fail due to the above error
info sharp Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/page/install for required dependencies
gyp WARN EACCES current user ("hellRaiser") does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.cache/node-gyp/12.16.3"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/home/hellRaiser/Desktop/devBlog/node_modules/sharp/.node-gyp"
make: Entering directory '/home/hellRaiser/Desktop/localhost@localhost:~/Desktop/devBlog$ sudo npm install
[sudo] password for hellRaiser: 
npm WARN tarball tarball data for typeface-montserrat@0.0.54 (sha512-Typhap0PWT299+Va0G/8ZtycHMXrH4gBWKfiW977KEBx5rXUUCa70gvqLx1fdA0WAo6bhSAQmo8uc+QFAmjPww==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for typeface-merriweather@0.0.72 (sha512-gO0+fcZ1fTyKUsYY1ltYOOTI6FmBGeEdyIfeQg9NL8aInndk0feiJJVJsKHm/DiyYrnQEezraAQhz/KQoqMGtw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.

> sharp@0.21.3 install /home/hellRaiser/Desktop/devBlog/node_modules/sharp
> (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)

ERR! sharp EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.npm'
info sharp Attempting to build from source via node-gyp but this may fail due to the above error
info sharp Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/page/install for required dependencies
gyp WARN EACCES current user ("hellRaiser") does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.cache/node-gyp/12.16.3"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/home/hellRaiser/Desktop/devBlog/node_modules/sharp/.node-gyp"
make: Entering directory '/home/hellRaiser/Desktop/devBlog/node_modules/sharp/build'
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/libvips-cpp.stamp
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o
../src/common.cc:25:10: fatal error: vips/vips8: No such file or directory
   25 | #include <vips/vips8>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [sharp.target.mk:138: Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/hellRaiser/Desktop/devBlog/node_modules/sharp/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-26-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/hellRaiser/Desktop/devBlog/node_modules/sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sharp@0.21.3 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.21.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-02T08_52_17_386Z-debug.log
localhost@localhost:~/Desktop/devBlog$ 

devBlog/node_modules/sharp/build'
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/libvips-cpp.stamp
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o
../src/common.cc:25:10: fatal error: vips/vips8: No such file or directory
   25 | #include <vips/vips8>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [sharp.target.mk:138: Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/hellRaiser/Desktop/devBlog/node_modules/sharp/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-26-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/hellRaiser/Desktop/devBlog/node_modules/sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sharp@0.21.3 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.21.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-02T08_52_17_386Z-debug.log
localhost@localhost:~/Desktop/devBlog$
```

Comment: I would reinstall node and npm. Also rm -rf node_modules and package-lock.json

Comment: why package-lock.json?

Comment: SOmetimes package-lock should be deleted to.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably due to build tools not installed. I've had this error also, the steps I took to resolve this:

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install build-essential
3. sudo apt autoremove (only if it says so)

`npm install` worked.

I was on ubuntu. You can try installing xcode tools if you're on Mac.

If the above doesn't work, then the problem is most probably due to unsupported version of node. In my case, swithching to node version `8.15.0` worked.