# npm install error: sqlite never downloads

Tags: linux, sqlite, npm-install, chromebook, node-pre-gyp

When running `npm install` to download project dependencies, `sqlite3` encounters an error and never installs. Trying `npm install sqlite3` produces same error.

Running on Linux Beta (Debian v10 buster) on ChromeOS.

Installs fine on others' machines. Expect it has something to do with ChromeOS.

Link to project files: https://github.com/andrewbruner/fsjs-techdegree-unit-09

```
 andrewbruner@penguin:~/treehouse/fsjs-techdegree-unit-09$ npm install

 > sqlite3@4.0.6 install /home/andrewbruner/treehouse/fsjs-techdegree-unit-09/node_modules/sqlite3
 > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

 node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
 node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.0.6/node-v72-linux-x64.tar.gz 
 node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@4.0.6 and node@12.16.3 (node-v72 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
 gyp ERR! build error 
 gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
 gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
 gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
 gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
 gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
 gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
 gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
 gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:167:21)
 gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.98-08076-g24ab33fb8e14
 gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/andrewbruner/treehouse/fsjs-techdegree-unit-09/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v72-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=/home/andrewbruner/treehouse/fsjs-techdegree-unit-09/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v72-linux-x64" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
 gyp ERR! cwd /home/andrewbruner/treehouse/fsjs-techdegree-unit-09/node_modules/sqlite3
 gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.3
 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
 gyp ERR! not ok 
 node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/andrewbruner/treehouse/fsjs-techdegree-unit-09/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v72-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/home/andrewbruner/treehouse/fsjs-techdegree-unit-09/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v72-linux-x64 --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/andrewbruner/treehouse/fsjs-techdegree-unit-09/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
 node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.98-08076-g24ab33fb8e14
 node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/andrewbruner/treehouse/fsjs-techdegree-unit-09/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
 node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/andrewbruner/treehouse/fsjs-techdegree-unit-09/node_modules/sqlite3
 node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.3
 node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
 node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
 Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/andrewbruner/treehouse/fsjs-techdegree-unit-09/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v72-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/home/andrewbruner/treehouse/fsjs-techdegree-unit-09/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v72-linux-x64 --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
 npm WARN techdegree-fullstackjs-rest-api@1.0.0 No repository field.
 npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/fsevents):
 npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno 1
 npm ERR! sqlite3@4.0.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
 npm ERR! Exit status 1
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@4.0.6 install script.
 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR!     /home/andrewbruner/.npm/_logs/2020-05-07T18_52_06_591Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`npm` can't download a prebuilt binary and thus falls back to building it with `node-gyp`. This is where the build fails.

Note the line in your log where it says: `gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make`

It seems as if you don't have `make` installed. Since you're on Debian, you should be able to install `make` by running: `sudo apt-get install build-essential`.

This question has already been extensively discussed in the following question: [npm failed to install time with make not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772508/npm-failed-to-install-time-with-make-not-found-error)

Make sure to take a close look at error messages :)